# How to completely remove a pre-authorized google account in R library googledrive?

Tags: r, google-drive-api

[image]

As you can see in the image above, I have associated two email ids in **R** library googledrive. Now I need to delete one permanently so that whenever I call `drive_auth()` only one shows up.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling googledrive package using `remove.packages()`. I have also tried to de-link the second account manually in https://myaccount.google.com/connections but it is still showing up. Is there any way to permanently remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The special authorization stuff to connect to google is handled by a package called "gargle". This package caches data about account outside the package folder so it can be persisted. The data is stored in the path returned by

```
rappdirs::user_cache_dir("gargle")
```

If you open that folder you should be able to delete the account that you want to disappear. If there is a function in the package itself to do this, I do not know what it is.